# angularjs factory best practice

Tags: angularjs

I know this question is going to be a bit debatable but I find this could actually be helpful to developers looking to do big projects with angularJS.

Best practices (according to John Papa at least) say that it's good to encapsulate angularjs controllers in an unanimous function and inject the providers/services/factories in them. So basically you would end up with something like this:

```
(function() {
    "use strict";

    angular
        .module("app.components")
        .controller("ctrl", ctrl);

    ctrl.$inject = ["$scope", "someFactory", "someOtherFactory"];

    function ctrl($scope, someFactory, someOtherFactory) {
        // controller logic
    }
});
```

If you work on a big project the most reasonable assumption is that you will want to have as less redundancy as possible so I ended up with having factories for each class of api endpoints from the server so I have them grouped by server scope.

In a complex screen, I will use maybe five to six of those and so you can imagine the inject starts to get long.

What I would want to do is have a "#data" that I can inject and through that #data I want to access the factories containing the $http calls.

My feeling is that this #data should not be a file containing all the configurations for the factories it redirects to but more like a provider where you can register with a configuration method the factory someting like this:

```
(function() {
    "use strict";

    angular
        .module("app.factory")
        .factory("someFactory", someFactory);

    someFactory.$inject = ["$http"];

    function someFactory($http) {
        // factory logic
    }

    angular
        .module("app")
        .config(someFactoryConfig);

    someFactoryConfig.$inject = ["#dataProvider"];

    function someFactoryConfig(#dataProvider) {
        #dataProvider.register("someFactory");
    }
});
```

This would be similar to how you define a state inside the ui-router.

Any ideas on how to implement the provider?

Comment: Just my two cents, but this seems like a disaster for code readability and upkeep that doesn't really add any functionality.

Comment: You make a fair point @nathan.meadows. The way I am looking at this is that I have a data module (all the $http calls) that is separate from the components part and hits helps with reusability. I prefer redundancy over readability since we have a developer guide to the app for our team and we train the new ones to understand the code base but having multiple injects can be a pain after a certain point

Answer (score 0):

I know this might not answer your question but Angular 2 tries to go away from `Controllers` and `$scope`.

Instead when you start your project you should plan it into features and from these features create different modules. Within these modules you will have all of your directives (components), services & factories to support the whole module.

This way you encapsulate your application into smaller applications. This will ensure that if 1 part of your application does not work the rest of your application will not be affected.

Angular can be a hard nut to crack and gets a lot of flame for that. But if you plan your project correctly Angular can be one of the most powerful frameworks out there.

Comment: i have my controllers planned into components. each component encapsulates : controller,view, router, style (sass) but not the data part. I keep my $http calls in a separate part of the project. If i also add these to eacn modules I am just adding a layer of complexity to it because if the server changes one of it's resources, i`m going to have to change it in multiple files and that's not something i am really looking forward to

Comment: @Blitz i see your point. I am guessing you have some sort of backend either a node server or any other service. What i usually do is make a data connection service that is being used in all of my factories. This way i will always be able to connect to my database and only changes to my node server has to be made.