# Best practices when creating Angular Services

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-services

I was wondering what should be considered when creating Angular `services` in regards to which module to attach the `services` too.

For example

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);

//Add service to app module
app.factory('helloWorld', function() {
  return {};
});

//Or create a module for the service, and include the module where needed
var helloWorldModule = angular.module('helloWorldModule', []);
helloWorldModule.factory('helloWorld', function() {
  return {};
});

//Or attach is to an existing module that may need it
existingModule.factory('helloWorld', function() {
  return {};
});
```

Should all services created be added to the `app` module, so I can ensure that I can access the service anywhere if I need to, or should I add it to only the `modules` that I know that will be using it.

I know that this may be subjective, and based on application structure, basically I am just wondering if it is ever a good idea to add  all services to the `app` module.

Comment: Hello :) please check my answer in the following question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36476271/angularjs-factory-best-practice/36478417#36478417

Comment: Here is a website explaining all the good methods for main used thing in angularjs : http://www.codestyle.co/Guidelines/angularjs

Answer (score 1):

As always it depends. If your service is an isolated service that can be shared across different applications and modules then the answer is yes.
If it is relevant only to your current module then no.

Answer (score -2):

Try to maximise the cohesion. If you only have a solution or app it doesn't matter where you place the service, but if you have multiple solutions, maybe during a refactoring process you realise that some services make sense to put them together in the same module.